# Sinon.js: avoid stubbing twice

Tags: javascript, sinon

Due to some design problems I have to stub an object's functions inside a special hook.

*Problem:* the hook can be invoked multiple times. Then I need to know whether the function has been already stubbed.

*Question:* How to avoid stubbing twice?

*Example:*

```
// throws "undefined is not a function" if `doSOmething`
obj.doSomething.restore(); hasn't been stubbed yet
sinon.stub(obj, "doSomething", function() { alert('Stub!'); });

//throw an exception if `doSomething` function has been already stubbed
sinon.stub(obj, "doSomething", function() { alert('Stub!'); });
```

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to test and the test itself and explain what you are trying to achieve. You cannot stub a function twice, but you can create different stubs for every call and tell how many times the stub was called.

Answer (score 1):

1.first test the function in the hook

2.test the hook function, stub/spy the hook

different level.